# React Native passing data from one page to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing a mobile app using React Native and expo-router.

I currently have HomeScreen that includes orders which were provided by an API, each order has an ID.

As per the documentation of 'expo-router' I created an `[id].js` file, and when I click on an order in the HomeScreen I call `router.push('/repairs/${id}')` to navigate to that screen.

I want to provide the relevant order details in the `[id].js` file (the details are already in HomeScreen).

**What I thought about doing:**

- Passing order details as params in the url, doesn't seem safe as the other can modify the url and thus change the content.
- `useContext` seems a bit overkill for data that won't need to be used widely
- Using the orderID to fetch the data from the API, I prefer not to use this option as am fetching already existing data and wasting API calls.

I would greatly appreciate advice on how to approach this.

Thanks